# adb push error in script

Tags: bash, adb

Here is my problem:

I just bought my Nexus 5X and I'm very happy with it. But I'm on mac and I like the command line, so I decided to write a script to send my music in a few steps:

1 - write on a file a list of the songs to send

2 - write on a file all the songs that are already on my Nexus' Music folder

3 - go through each line of the file where there are the files to send, check if this line is a song on the phone or not, and if not send it.

And I can't have the last step to work, it prints the adb help page for each step of the loop.

Here is the script :

```
#!/bin/bash


#####################
##### FUNCTIONS #####
#####################

usage()
{
    echo "usage: sendMusicNexus.sh"
}

error_exit() 
{
    # Display error message and exit
    echo "${0}: ${1:-"Unknown Error"}" 1>&2
    exit 1
}

#####################
######## Main #######
#####################

# Check if the device is connected
if [ `adb devices | wc -l` -ne 3 ]; then
    error_exit "Device not found"
fi

# List all the files to send, sort and uniq (Artist/Album/*.mp3)
cat ~/.mpd/playlists/*.m3u > allsongstosend
sort -o allsongstosend allsongstosend ; uniq allsongstosend allsongstosenduniq
rm allsongstosend

# List all the files in the Music folder of the Nexus (name.mp3)
adb shell ls -R /storage/self/primary/Music | grep mp3 > allsongsthere

# Loop through the files to send
while read SONG
do
    # Keep the name under the pattern song.mp3
    temp=$(echo $SONG | rev | cut -d / -f 1 | rev)
    # Look for the file in the list of what's in the phone
    grep -q "$temp" allsongsthere

    # If it's not, push it
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        adb push ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music/${SONG} /storage/self/primary/Music/${SONG}
    fi
done < allsongstosenduniq
```

How can I get this to work ?

Thanks !

Edit -- It seems that the problem come from the fact that in the m3u files, the path to the songs is written with non-escaped space... I'll look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
adb push "~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music/${SONG}" "/storage/self/primary/Music/${SONG}"
```

instead of your own line

Comment: I had to modify it by putting the absolute path, but once I did that it worked ! Thanks !